# Can wasm-pack compile a rust project including C++ code that uses stdlib?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-pack

I am trying to compile a rust project into WebAssembly with wasm-pack. One of [its dependencies](https://github.com/tlaplus-community/tree-sitter-tlaplus) is a rust wrapper around C++ code. This dependency can, on its own, be successfully compiled to WebAssembly with Emscripten. However if I try to compile my project or the dependency itself with wasm-pack I get the following error:

```
  running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-I" "src" "-Wall" "
-Wextra" "-o" "/home/ahelwer/src/tlaplus/tree-sitter-tlaplus/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/tree-sitter-tlaplus-90
d9bfea3134c6dd/out/src/parser.o" "-c" "src/parser.c"
  cargo:warning=In file included from src/parser.c:1:
  cargo:warning=src/tree_sitter/parser.h:10:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
  cargo:warning=#include <stdlib.h>
  cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=1 error generated.
  exit status: 1
```

So it can't find libc. I know Emscripten includes the ability to link programs against the libc (based on musl) it comes with. Does wasm-pack also have this ability? Do you have to modify the `build.rs` file of the native dependency in some way?

Comment: You could in theory [hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73615409/401059) your C++ compiler a full stdlib via `CFLAGS=--sysroot=/path/to/wasi-sysroot`. If you're lucky, it won't result in any wasi-related imports and you can use the module as is, but in general, it seems wasm-pack [doesn't](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/741#issuecomment-1094064702) support this.

Comment: @Caesar thanks for the pointers! What do you mean by wasi-related imports? Like I should hope the dependency links against stdlib functions to compile but those functions are never called during runtime, and if they were it would be a dynamic library load failure?

Comment: Quite close. Two small nits: 1. Some of the stdlib functions (e.g. `sqrt`) don't actually interact with the "OS", so they require no imports 2. The fact that functions that require imports (e.g. `fwrite`) are never called has to be realized by the optimizer/linker, and it actually has to remove the functions/imports at link time. (Not sure when exactly the removing happens.)